# Map two stream event sources to the same lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

According to [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-kinesis.html#services-kinesis-eventsourcemapping), it is possible to map multiple event sources (in my case Kinesis stream) to the same lambda.

In Terraform [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lambda_event_source_mapping), `aws_lambda_event_source_mapping` only shows one `event_source_arn` mapped to one lambda function

I couldn't find any further examples. How can I go about doing this mapping?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to create two `aws_lambda_event_source_mapping` resources. For example:

```
resource "aws_lambda_event_source_mapping" "kinesis1" {
 # ...
}

resource "aws_lambda_event_source_mapping" "kinesis2" {
 # ...
}
```

Depending on how you want to custuct them, you can also use `count` or `for_each` instead of explicitly creating two different versions of  `aws_lambda_event_source_mapping`.